# Migration from Struts 2.2.3 to 2.5

Tags: java, struts2

I have one challenging task that we need to migrate our application developed over struts 2.2.3 to latest struts 2.5 version. As per my findings about the migration, we do need to replace the core jars plus we need to have a lot of changes in the tag-libs that we use in our JSPs.

Since our project has too many JSPs and it is really difficult to fix all of the JSPs in a really limited time frame, I was just wondering that is there some way so that I can upgrade to struts 2.5 core lib by using old taglibs and dojo frameworks. Our migration is because of some vulnerablilities in struts 2.2.3 core library.

Comment: https://svn.apache.org/repos/infra/websites/production/struts/content/docs/struts-23-to-25-migration.html#Struts2.3to2.5migration-StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter

Comment: This link recommends to change all of the taglibs that are affected. I want to have a workaround by having which I can replace only the core jar by keeping all of the JSPs and taglibs intact.

Comment: @user1185970 It's not clear what tag issues you're referring to. Changing `id` to `var`? Seems like a regex search/replace would handle that, but even with many JSPs, doing it manually isn't much time effort. Please just upgrade your app properly. The tags are in the struts2-core jar anyway, and if you bust it up and attempt to mix versions you're in uncharted, risky waters. Just do it right.

Comment: Alright. I am not going to migrate to struts 2.5 all the way. Can any one here help me getting the pom.xml with complete dependencies of struts 2.5. I am trying to do so but getting missing artificat errors.